# How to get user in systemd unit who caused an event

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to get the name of an active user in systemd units? I guess I could parse output of `who` or do something like that, but I believe there should be a native way of doing that in systemd.

I also know there is `logind` which tells me a bit more information about the users, but if there were more seats, I would like to know who the single user who caused the event was, e.g. if someone wrote `systemctl suspend` to only lock his session at his seat and let the computer handle all the other seats. It is probably not the best example but I hope it illustrates the problem better, I only want the one user who caused systemd units to run.

Namely I wanted to create a systemd unit that will lock the user's current session when going to sleep and right now I resorted to trying to lock all sessions. I believe this to be a bad solution and would like to know how to do this properly.

Comment: @StephenKitt I put some more information there, even though the other question is useful for me, I don't believe it solves my problem as a whole. I was actually already using `logind` to list all the sessions when locking them, but I would like to know what user/session caused the unit to run

Comment: Why are your users running `systemctl suspend` to lock their session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong and now I know it. Everything systemd oriented is run by root and I just thought it was not because of some experiments I have done earlier.

There is no way to figure out who is sitting at the computer, I can only get the full list of logged users.

Comment: Except there is a way to figure out who is sitting at the computer...

Comment: @Stephen Kitt and would you share?

Comment: See the linked duplicate (and my answer there).

Comment: @StephenKitt to qoute myself from December of last year "I was actually already using logind to list all the sessions [...], but I would like to know what user/session caused the unit to run". I hoped there would be a way to know which user caused the system to run a unit (if it was not something like lid close). `logind` just narrows the guess if there is more than one session